# Unable to insert citation in LaTeX using BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am new to LaTeX and have just started using it today. I know this question has been asked a few times on this forum, however I am still not sure why I am unable to load citations from the BibTeX library.

I exported all my EndNote references into BibDesk app. I am using TeXshop to edit the tex file.

**EDIT** New File

HelloWorld.tex file.

```
\documentclass{article}     % use "amsart" instead of "article" for AMSLaTeX format
\begin{document}
Hello World \cite{RN10}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{~/Documents/Test_bib}
\end{document}
```

This is what my BibTeX library looks like

[image]

When i try to run this tex file using TeXshop i get the

```
LaTex Warning: Citation 'RN13' on page 1 undefined on input line 5
```

[image]

The citation call-out appears as [?] in the pdf file.

**EDIT:**
I tried including the {} but I am getting another error now when i compile with `BibText` the error looks like this [image]

And when I run with `LaTex`. [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Using `(` and `)` instead of `{` and `}` to delimit the argument of a macro is a syntax error. What happens if you change `\bibliography(~/Documents/Test_bib)` to `\bibliography{~/Documents/Test_bib}` and try to recompile?

Comment: Off-topic: It looks like you haven't updated your TeXLive2019 distribution in a while, as your log file shows that it's using `LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>`. For what it's worth, the *current* version is `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 4`. Do consider running `sudo tlmgr update --self --all` at a command prompt.

Comment: @Mico I am getting a different error message after replacing the brackets with parantheses.

Comment: @calveen -- And what would this "different error message" be? (I'm very sorry, by my divination skills are absolutely worthless.)

Comment: Also is `~/` notation actually supported? What happens if you move the bib file to the same folder as the tex file, use `\bibliography{Test_bib} ` and then run pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex.

Comment: There is also something about on a Mac you have two `~` characters, one is the ascii tilde the other is the utf8 equivalent of `\sim` which may explain the math error. Some editors map both `~` keyboard chars to ascii tilde others do not.

Comment: @Mico The error msg is in the edited post. Thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: @daleif Hey ur suggestion helped me fix the error ! Thanks :-)

Comment: According to the BibDesk screenshot, the bib file contains only entries with keys RN7 and RN14. In contrast, your tex file would appear to try to cite an entry with keys RN10. If an entry doesn't exist, then LaTeX and BibTeX cannot do much useful stuff. Incidentally, what exactly do you mean when you write "I tried including the {}"; does it actually that you replaced the round parentheses with curly braces?

Comment: @Mico sorry Mico i only showed a portion of the screenshot. How i got RN10 was i dragged one of the listed rows to latex

Comment: @daleif -- Your conjecture sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A few things have already been fixed. I just want to explain the errors seen.

First of all, I'm not sure LaTeX even supports the `~/` syntax, as we need a shell to resolve it.

But that is not the problem here. On a Mac keyboard there is actually two `~`! One is the ascii tilde (which is an active char in LaTeX meaning non-breaking space) the other is the UTF-8 equivalent of the `\sim` symbol, which coincidentally requires math mode when you insert it into the document.

So the first error is the math mode `~` and the second error is the expansion of the ascii tilde, which does not expand  to something that are normally found in a path.

Suggestion: move `Test_bib.bib` to the same folder as your `.tex`, use

```
\bibliography{Test_bib}
```

Then run pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex and pdflatex

NB: I've seen some LaTeX editors map both tilde chars to ascii tilde, but others do not.

Comment: Using `~` shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Johannes_B see the second of the three images, isn't that the expansion of the active ascii tilde?